# IDA patching, How to add new code, create new variable?

Tags: assembly, ida, codecave

I have a very basic knowledge about IDA and patching. From my understanding, I can change a line of code by doing `Edit -> Patch program -> Assembly`. But how to I go about adding new lines of code into program?

The existing variable can also be change by doing `Patch program-> Change byte`, how can new variable be added?

Comment: Find an unused place to put your code (or create one by adding a section to the file). The term to google for is `code cave`.

Answer (score 0):

add new code:
as CherryDT said,Find an unused place to put your code (or create one by adding a section to the file). jump to ...then jump return.

create new variable:
no need to do this,"add new code" can do everything.